# Choose one video and make sure the others are paused

Tags: javascript, html, function, video, modal-dialog

I'm working on a website for my girlfriend and I'm trying to get my programming chops back after not doing any for years.

I have div where you select a picture and it opens a modal where it will play the corresponding video and thumbnails at the bottom to choose another video to play. I need to make sure all other videos are paused when I choose a video. There are 4 videos total.
So, I guess this is more of a procedural question.
How do I do this? I'm using html5 and javascript for the coding. I thought of a switch function, but that doesn't seem right to me. I could use a whole bunch of if-else-if statements, but there has to be a better way. 
So, basically:
choose video2: set 1, 3, & 4 to pause.
choose video1: set 2, 3, & 4 to pause.

What kind of construct should I use to code that efficiently?

Comment: Find all the video object in the page and pause all but the one you want. For example if you have four video object that are enclosed in div, based on the number of div or based on the ids of the div you could find the video and take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with videos so I don't know the available functions, but here is some example JavaScript assuming that the video object has a play and pause method.

Example JavaScript:

```
/**
 * Stores all references to the available video objects.
 */
var videos = {
    "1": {...},
    "2": {...},
    "3": {...},
    "4": {...}  
};
/**
 * Called when user clicks on video thumbnail. This will pause all videos expect for the video that needs to be played.
 *
 * @param {String} videoKey    The key that represents the video to play (i.e. "1", "2", "3", "4")
 */
var playVideo = function(videoKey) {
    /**
     * Pause all videos.
     */
    for (var key in videos) {
        videoToPause = videos[key];
        videoToPause.pause();
    }
    /**
     * Play the requested video.
     */
    var videoToPlay = videos[videoKey]; 
    videoToPlay.play();
};
```

Example HTML:

```
...
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="playVideo('1')">Video 1</button>
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="playVideo('2')">Video 2</button>
...
```

Comment: I took the lazy way out and paused all four videos for each time I needed to pause one.